# Get a record from a included list based on value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a repository that returns customers. But a customer can have more then 1 contract. How can I get the customer by contract number.

I have this :

```
return await context.Customers
    .Include(x => x.Contracts)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Contracts.FirstOrDefault().ContractNumber == contractNumber);
```

With this it returns off course always the first record of the table...

Comment: Did you try with `Any()`? `.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cust => cust.Contracts.Any(cont => cont.ContractNumber == contractNumber));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"How can I get the customer by contract number."*

You can change your query to return the first customer where `Any` of their contracts have a number that matches:

```
return await context.Customers
    .Include(cust => cust.Contracts)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cust => 
        cust.Contracts.Any(contract => contract.ContractNumber == contractNumber));
```